# how can i run multiple functions with return in parallel in python 3.4

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I need to run multiple search functions in parallel and combine the search result in a single dictionary.Like this:

```
def search1(key):
    ...........
    search_result = {}
    ...........
    return search_result

def search2(key):
    ...........
    search_result = {}
    ...........
    return search_result
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Define parallel. Is it for speed-up or would it do to just run them sequentially and concatenate their results in the end?

Comment: You can achieve this by using [threading](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html). You also might want to read [this article](http://effbot.org/zone/thread-synchronization.htm#synchronizing-access-to-shared-resources) about shared resources and how to avoid data races.

Comment: want to parallelize it to speed up execution time of these functions